# Mysql filter SELECT query result.

Tags: mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumResults, race_date AS RaceDate, race_time AS RaceTime
FROM results 
WHere jockeys_claim = 10
GROUP BY race_date DESC, race_time ASC
```

I would then like to filter out the NumResults , so the table only shows results where the NumResults = 1. Thanks for looking.

Comment: WHERE jockeys_claim = 10 AND NumResults = 1?

Comment: Your query is incorrect. You cannot have ASC and DESC in the GROUP BY clause, do you mean ORDER BY ? Please fix that first

Comment: I get #1054 - Unknown column 'NumResults' in 'where clause'

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumResults, race_date AS RaceDate, race_time AS RaceTime
FROM results 
WHere jockeys_claim = 10 AND NumResults = '1'
GROUP BY race_date, race_time

Comment: Still get the #1054 - Unknown column 'NumResults' in 'where clause'

Comment: No, it was actually stupid by me, did somehow read over the AS. And as far as I know that's not working like that, since you'd have to have an intermediate result table. The answer by Thomas G should be fine though.

Comment: Thanks for looking maio290

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` clause to filter the results of an aggregate function (the `COUNT` in your case)

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS NumResults, race_date AS RaceDate, race_time AS RaceTime
FROM results 
WHere jockeys_claim = 10
GROUP BY race_date, race_time
HAVING COUNT(id) = 1
ORDER BY race_date DESC, race_time ASC
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I am only leaning and this has taught me a lot. Very much appreciated.